# NextJS calling api route from another api route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to use fetch api from inside api route in NextJs? I have quite a big handler and instead of doing everything in one handler I would like to make it more modular so that after doing a job that is made for (file name el. write-to-db) I would like to call another handler eg (send-emails). Is it possible in NextJS?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just put everything into different functions (and/or files) and call them sequentially? You shouldn't be calling internal API routes for other API routes.

Comment: 2 reasons are caching and consistency of code.  Also that API call might live somewhere else one day, and ideally that would mean just changing the url

Answer (score 5):

```
const baseUrl = process.env.VERCEL_URL ? 'https://' + process.env.VERCEL_URL : 'http://localhost:3000'

await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/[your-route-name-here]`)
```